# MapDispatchToPros with event

Tags: redux, action, stateless

I have this part of my code:

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
        symbol: '',
        side: '',
        status: ''
      };

      this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
      this.onValueChangeSide = this.onValueChangeSide.bind(this);
      this.onValueChangeStatus = this.onValueChangeStatus.bind(this);
      this.onFormSelect = this.onFormSelect.bind(this);
  }

    onInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({ symbol: event.target.value });
      }

      onValueChangeSide(event) {
        this.setState({ side: event.target.value});
      }

      onValueChangeStatus(event) {
        this.setState({ status: event.target.value});
      }

      onFormSelect(event) {
        this.props.requestAccountsFilter(this.state.symbol, this.state.side, 

this.state.status);
  }
```

The requestAccountsFilter is an Action. Its code is:

```
export function requestAccountsFilter(symbol, side, status) {
  return {
    type: ACCOUNT_FILTERS,
    payload: {
      symbol,
      side,
      status
    }
  };
}
```

That approach works fine.

Furthermore, i want to make my component Stateless so i create a container. My problem is that i don't know how to dispatch my action with the above functionality.
I write this:

```
const MapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  {
    requestAccountsFilter: (symbol, side, status) => {
      dispatch(requestAccountsFilter(symbol, side, status));
    }
  }
);
```

but it didn't work.
How to dispatch my action in the MapDispatchToProps??

Answer (score 0):

**The purpose of mapDispatchToProps is not to actually dispatch actions directly.**

mapDispatchToProps is used to  bind action creators with dispatch and pass these new bound functions as props to the component.

The main benefit of using mapDispatchToProps is that it makes our code cleaner by abstracting away the store's dispatch method from components. Therefore we can call props that are functions without acces to dispatch like so

```
this.props.onTodoClick(id);
```

Whereas if we didn't use mapDispatchToProps then we would have to pass dispatch separately to components and dispatch actions like so:

```
this.props.dispatch(toggleTodo(id));
```

You would use mapDispatchToProps as shown in your example code, and then elsewhere write:

**mapDispatchToProps must be a pure function and cannot have side effects.**

Dispatching actions from inside the function would be considered a side effect. A function has one or more 'side effects' when the evaluation of the function changes state outside of itself (changes global state of app)

**Instead use lifecycle hooks to dispatch actions in response to prop changes on components:**

```
class exampleComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData(this.props.id)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.id !== this.props.id) {
      this.props.fetchData(this.props.id)
    }
  }

  // ...

}
```